# Azure Blob Storage SDK 12 compress files by GZipStream not working

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-blob-storage

I use the same code for gzipping streams all the time in the same way.
But for some reason it does not work in Azure.Storage.Blobs version 12.6.0 lib

```
        m_currentFileName = Guid.NewGuid() + ".txt.gz";
        var blockBlob = new BlockBlobClient(m_connectionString, m_containerName, GetTempFilePath());

        using (var stream = await blockBlob.OpenWriteAsync(true))
        using (var currentStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Compress))
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(currentStream))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("Hello world!");
        }
```

After that I got 0B file in Azure Blob Storage
[image]

The code without GZipStream works as expected.
I found lots of code examples with a copy data to a MemoryStream first but I do not wanna keep my data in RAM. I did not find any issues on StackOverflow or Azure Blob Storage GitHub. So I may do something wrong here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It appears `GZipStream` stream needs to be explicitly closed, according to [`GZipStream.Write` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream.write?view=netcore-3.1)

> The write operation might not occur immediately but is buffered until
> the buffer size is reached or until the Flush or Close method is
> called.

For example:

```
  using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
  {
      using (var gzipStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
      using (var writer = new StreamWriter(gzipStream))
      {
          writer.Write("Hello world!");
      }
      stream.Position = 0;
      await blockBlob.UploadAsync(stream);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Close is called in Dispose() method of GZipStream so using must do it's work. As I wrote I've already found some solutions with MemoryStream but it obliges to store all the data in RAM first and only then write the whole stream in blockBlob. It requires more time and memory than just streaming all data through streams.